# Accessing Serialized Hash via ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, serialization, hash

I have a serialized hash in MyModel, like this:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
    serialize :times, Hash
end
```

I am able to write to and read from the serialzed hash, like this:

```
# write
my_model.times[:weekday] = "foo"

# read
bar = my_model.times[:weekend]
```

But I am running into syntax errors around `times[:weekday]`, while trying something like this:

```
MyModel.where("foo = ? AND times[:weekday] IS NOT NULL", baz)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Your Database doesn't know the times column is actually a Hash, it is only Ruby on Rails that knows it. You DB consider this field as a string. You can't set conditions on the serialized columns, only the NULL tests (which is never true since an empty array will not be considered as NULL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
MyModel.where("foo = ?", baz).select { |m| m.weekday.present? }
```

?

Comment: I think you meant `.select{ |m| m.times[:weekday].present? }`